# How to display the most recent post of each category of a custom post type in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

This question seems to have been asked in some varieties, But mine is quite specific.

I need to display the most recent post of all categories of a custom post type called "products". I need to display the category instead of the title and link to that cat's archive.

The problem is, What I am getting instead is only one post of that general post type. Any thoughts?

Here is my starting point:

```
<?php

        $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'post_type' => 'products',
        'post_status'=>'publish',
        'orderby'=>'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'cat' => $category->term_id,
        'count'=>1,

        ));

         if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">

                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="pos-rel"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('product', array('class' => 'img-responsive center-block')); ?><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>

                <?php else : ?>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="featured-products pos-rel"><!--<img class="img-responsive center-block" src="<?php echo THEME_DIR; ?>/img/default-thumb.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />--><img class="img-responsive " data-src="holder.js/100%174/auto" alt="Generic placeholder image"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>

                <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- col-sm-6 -->

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div><!-- end row -->
        <ul class="pager">
            <li class="previous"><?php previous_posts_link(); ?></li>
            <li class="next"><?php next_posts_link(); ?></li>
        </ul>

        <?php else : ?>
        <h1>Not Found</h1>
        <p><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="Home">Click Here to return to the Home Page</a></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

The custom post type was created via a 3rd plug into [Super CPT](https://wordpress.org/plugins/super-cpt/) Plugin

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'setup_data_structures' );
function setup_data_structures() {
if ( ! class_exists( 'Super_Custom_Post_Type' ) )
return;
```

$products = new Super_Custom_Post_Type( 'products', 'Product', 'Products' );

`# Test Icon. Should be a square grid.
$products->set_icon( 'suitcase' );


# Taxonomy test, should be like categories
$product_category = new Super_Custom_Taxonomy(  'product-category', 'Product Category', 'Product Categories', 'category' );

# Connect both of the above taxonomies with the post type
connect_types_and_taxes( $products, array($product_category) );

# Add a meta box with every field type
$products->add_meta_box( array(
    'id'      => 'product-fields',
    'context' => 'normal',
    'fields'  => array(
    'client-name'        => array('column' => true ),
        'product-description'        => array( 'type' => 'wysiwyg' )
    )
) );`

$products->add_to_columns( 'product-category' );

Comment: I'm not sure about the plugin because I create my own plugins via the functions file.

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'product',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Products' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );
}

Comment: That is what I would have done. But I am stock with a previous developers work here.

Comment: is your problem resolved? Did you try removing  'count'=>1,

Answer (score 1):

This should help you out. The follow code displays 5 of each category. Just switch the 5 to how many ever you wish to display from each category.

```
 <?php 
    $cat_args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'post_type' => 'products',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'child_of' => 0
    );

$categories =   get_categories($cat_args); 

foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<dl>';
    echo '<dt> <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a></dt>';

     $post_args = array(
      'numberposts' => 5,
      'category' => $category->term_id 
    );

    $posts = get_posts($post_args);

    foreach($posts as $post) {
    ?>
        <dd><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></dd>
    <?php 
    } 
    echo '<dd class="view-all"> <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>View all posts in ' . $category->name.'</a></dd>';
    echo '</dl>';
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Correct. Add the post type to the $cat_args

'post_type' => 'products'

Comment: Thanks. Still produces an outcome of the posts, not the custom post type.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $cats = array('3d-mail', 'boxes', 'folders', 'binders');
    $exclude_posts = array();
    foreach( $cats as $cat )
    {
        // build query argument
        $query_args = array(
            'category_name' => $cat,
            'showposts' => 1,
            'post_type' => 'products',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC'
        );

        // exclude post that already have been fetched
        // this would be useful if multiple category is assigned for same post
        if( !empty($exclude_posts) )
            $query_args['post__not_in'] = $exclude_posts;

        // do query
        $query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

        // check if query have any post
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

            // start loop
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                // set post global
                $query->the_post();

                // add current post id to exclusion array
                $exclude_posts[] = get_the_ID();


                <?php the_content(); ?>
            }
        } else {
            // no posts found
        }

        // Restore original Post Data
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you. But this lists the main categories. Not those under my custom post type.

Comment: Correct. Add the post type to the $cat_args 'post_type' => 'products'

Comment: I have updated the code to reflect your custom post type.

Comment: Still the same. I think the problem is with that loop.

Comment: did you change $cats = array('lifestyle', 'fashion', 'beauty'); to reflect the names of your categories. Also in the code if a category is empty it will exclude.